# Unable to override framework.disallow_search_engine_index

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to use an environment variable to (dis)allow search engine indexing, but without luck. I'm using Symfony 4.4.

```
# config/framework.yaml

parameters:
    env(APP_SECRET): SECRETASDF
    env(APP_ENV): dev
    env(DISALLOW_SEARCH_ENGINE_INDEX): true
    app.disallow_search_engine_index: '%env(bool:DISALLOW_SEARCH_ENGINE_INDEX)%'

framework:
    disallow_search_engine_index: '%app.disallow_search_engine_index%'
```

Setting `DISALLOW_SEARCH_ENGINE_INDEX=false` in `.env.local` doesn't change anything (it gets loaded, I double checked that).

After playing around with the settings, the only way is to set `framework.disallow_search_engine_index: false` in my configuration. But I want to use an environment variable for simplicity.

Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/38412 it looks like I'm abusing env variables here. The better way would be [configuring a new environment](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/configuration.html#configuration-environments).